# Zend_Acl error in Magento 1.5.0.1

Tags: magento-1.5, acl, developer-mode

I did fresh install of Magento 1.5.0.1 and turn on the developer mode in index.php:

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

When I try to login to the backend then it shows me the error like:

```
Zend_Acl_Exception: Resource 'admin/catalog/feed' not found in lib\Zend\Acl.php on line 365
Zend_Acl_Exception: Resource 'admin/catalog/feed/import_products' not found in lib\Zend\Acl.php on line 365
Zend_Acl_Exception: Resource 'admin/catalog/feed/import_items' not found in lib\Zend\Acl.php on line 365
Zend_Acl_Exception: Resource 'admin/report/products/bestsellers' not found in lib\Zend\Acl.php on line 365
Zend_Acl_Exception: Resource 'admin/report/refresh_statistics' not found in lib\Zend\Acl.php on line 365
Zend_Acl_Exception: Resource 'admin/all' not found in lib\Zend\Acl.php on line 365
```

Just wondering why Magento itself doesn't run without errors on strict developer mode?
I can't turn off the developer mode in order to skip those errors.

Any idea if this is a bug or else?

**Note**: I have enabled the xdebug extension.

**EDIT:**
I have only following row for table admin_rule:

```
rule_id  role_id  resource_id  privileges  assert_id  role_type  permission  
-------  -------  -----------  ----------  ---------  ---------  ------------
      1        1  all                              0  G          allow
```

Comment: Does your table admin_rule contain these entries?

Comment: @TobiasZander Please check my EDIT portion.

Comment: I have a similar error after update my magento installation to newest version. Still can't find solution how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

> I did fresh install of Magento 1.5.0.1

Why? 1.5.0.1 is an old, very buggy release

A clean installation won't throw any errors by default - so it sounds simply like a failed installation.

Try installing again with clean `tar.gz` archives from Magento. Or use an [automated installer](http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/fully-automated-magento-install-script/).

Comment: I have to install 1.5.0.1 as i have to develop one extension for a client whose store is in 1.5.0.1 version. Also i have seen that Magento 1.7 gives ..unable to save error when you try to save the system configuration with developer mode turned on.

Comment: If its happening with two different releases - then again, either your installation process is wrong - or your environment is broken. There is no core bugs related to having developer mode turned on.